# How to add Rate limit to dm_all command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using the code below to dm every member on the server and sometimes bot get rate limted at ultimately banned. I know this is against tos but out of curiosity I am asking is there a way I can add a limit to the bot like it send only 30 dms per minute and continues it until it send dms to every user on my server.

Here is the code I am using:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def dm_all(ctx, *, args=None):
    
    if args != None:
        members = ctx.guild.members
        for member in members:
            try:
                await member.send(args)
                await ctx.channel.send(" sent to: " + member.name)

            except:
                await ctx.channel.send("Couldn't send to: " + member.name)

    else:
        await ctx.channel.send("Please provide a message to send!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply tracking how many users you sended dms to. And then wait 60 seconds after 30 dms, can be used to avoid being rate limited.

Code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def dm_all(ctx, *, args=None):
    sended_dms = 0
    rate_limit_for_dms = 30
    time_to_wait_to_avoid_rate_limit = 60

    if args != None:
        members = ctx.guild.members
        for member in members:
            try:
                await member.send(args)
                await ctx.channel.send(" sent to: " + member.name)

            except:
                await ctx.channel.send("Couldn't send to: " + member.name)
            sended_dms += 1
            if sended_dms % rate_limit_for_dms == 0: # used to check if 30 dms are sent
                asyncio.sleep(time_to_wait_to_avoid_rate_limit) # wait till we can continue

    else:
        await ctx.channel.send("Please provide a message to send!")
```

Comment: it didn't work for me! Bot is sending dms as usual without pause

Comment: Yes, it only pauses after each 30 dms sent. How did you test? If you use less than 30 people to test the code on you will indeed see no difference

Comment: how can I randomize the frequency between the dms? like I set 1,2,3 and for each dm bot chooses between them and sends the dm then wait then send the dm

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
  sent_dms = 0
  #Send Dm here
  sent_dms += 1
    if sent_dms == 30:
      asyncio.sleep(60)
      sent_dms = 0
```

Comment: The answer can be improved with some explanation.